# H2 BLOB data type size

Tags: blob, h2

Does H2 have a notion of a specific size limit for the BLOB data type? The documentation (https://h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#blob_type) states that you can optionally set a limit e.g. `BLOB(10K)`, so does that mean that `BLOB()` is unlimited in size?

Similarly, the documentation lists `TINYBLOB`, `MEDIUMBLOB` etc. as acceptable keywords, but doesn't give any specific meaning for them. Are they simply aliases to `BLOB` for compatibility with other database dialects?

(I see that the `BINARY` type has a limit of 2Gb, which is what makes me think that `BLOB` doesn't have a limit since it's not specified.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BINARY` / `VARBINARY` data types are limited to available memory and they also have a strong limit slightly below 2 GB (it is limited to the maximum array size in Java). Note that `BINARY` should be used only when you have values with a known fixed size. In H2 1.4.200 `BINARY` is an alias for `VARBINARY`, but in the not yet released next version they are different.

`BLOB` values can be much larger. They aren't loaded into memory, they are streamed instead. There is some outdated information about limits in the documentation: https://h2database.com/html/advanced.html#limits_limitations
but this part of documentation was written for an old storage engine of H2, H2 uses another storage engine by default. Anyway, both engines support large binary and character objects.

`TINYBLOB`, `MEDIUMBLOB`, etc. don't have any special meaning, they are for compatibility only. Don't use them.